# How to set multi validation to form control?

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a simple form with **one** input. I want to set **multi validation** in this input. I can set one validation for this like below but I want to set multi validation. please help me
this is my Html code:

```
   <form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
       <div class="input-holder">
          <input type="text" maxlength="11" inputmode="numeric" digitOnly formControlName="phoneNumber" />
          <input type="submit" value="دریافت لینک دانلود" [disabled]="!contactForm.valid">
       </div>
   </form>
```

and this is the ts file:

```
contactForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.contactForm = new FormGroup({
      phoneNumber: new FormControl("", [Validators.required])
    });
  }
 onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.contactForm.value);
  }
```

**I want to set**

```
Validators.minLength(11)
```

**and**

```
Validators.maxLength(11)
```

**and ...**

Comment: you can set it like this `[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(11),Validators.maxLength(11)]` in array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since FormControl validatorOrOpts is array you can set multiple Validation like this

```
constructor() {
    this.contactForm = new FormGroup({
      phoneNumber: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(11)])
    });
  }
```

or use [Validators.compose](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#compose)

> Compose multiple validators into a single function that returns the
>   union of the individual error maps for the provided control

```
 constructor() {
    this.contactForm = new FormGroup({
      phoneNumber: new FormControl("", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(11)]))
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Complete Working Example You can find out in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11gdsy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-validator.directive.ts),

**Thought, Answer** is already accepted and have working solution I have to give one of the robust solution for applying custom-validation multiple times.. *At first it feels very long but at Long-Run of application scaling and re-usability You can re-use Your Own Custom-Validator-Function multiple time.*

**For Example**, If you have pass-word field and you want to make that pass-word field to make validation like PassWord must have below validations...

- Required
- At least one SMALL letter is allowed
- At least one UPPER letter is allowed
- At least one NUMERIC letter is allowed
- At least one SPECIAL-CHARACTER is allowed
- At least Eight Letter is allowed

So Doing this type of Multiple validation in angular we are going to use one **custom-Validation-Function-directive** for better angular support. Create new file `custom-validator.directive` and then in this file put this code...

```
import{AbstractControl, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';

export function customValidation(): ValidatorFn{
      return (control: AbstractControl) : {[key:string]: boolean} | null =>{
             const errorObject = {};

             const SMALL_LETTER_REGEXP = /^(?=.*[a-z])/;
             const UPPER_LETTER_REGEXP = /^(?=.*[A-Z])/;
             const NUMERIC_REGEXP = /^(?=.*[0-9])/;
             const SPECIAL_CHAR_REGEXP = /^(?=.*\W)/;
             const AT_LEAST_EIGHT_REGEXP = /^(?=.{8,})/

             if (SMALL_LETTER_REGEXP.test(control.value)){
             }else {
                 errorObject['atLeastOneSmallLetter'] = true;
              }
             if (UPPER_LETTER_REGEXP.test(control.value)){
             }else {
                errorObject['atLeastOneUpperLetter'] = true;
              }
            if(NUMERIC_REGEXP.test(control.value)){
            }else {
                errorObject['atLeastOneNumeric'] = true;
            }
            if(SPECIAL_CHAR_REGEXP.test(control.value)){
            }else {
                errorObject['atLeastOneSpecialChar'] = true;
            }
            if(AT_LEAST_EIGHT_REGEXP.test(control.value)){
            }else {
                errorObject['atLeastOneEightLength'] = true;
            }
         return errorObject;
      };
}
```

Now import this file in your component.ts where your `formsGroup` and `FormsBuilder` is there...

```
import {customValidation} from './custom-validator.directive';

export class AppComponent  {
    formGroup: FormGroup;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
                             password: ['', [ Validators.required,  customValidation()]]
            })
    }
    get password(){
        return this.formGroup.get('password');
    }
}
```

In, Above code in this line `password: ['', [ Validators.required,  customValidation()]]`, we are passing `customValidation()` function into the `formGroup`. this way we are applying all validations in this `password` form-control.

So each and every input key-field changes we are checking all password rules validation asynchronously. And tell user to enter only valid password matching character strings...

Your **Template.HTML** is

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
     <div  class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label for="password">Enter Pass-Word</label>
         <input id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" formControlName="password" >

     </div>

     <div class="col-md-6 " *ngIf="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched)">
         <div class="alert alert-danger " *ngIf="password.hasError('required')">
            <ul> <li> Required  </li> </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.hasError('atLeastOneSmallLetter')">
            <ul> <li> At least one SMALL letter is allowed  </li> </ul> 
         </div>
         <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.hasError('atLeastOneUpperLetter')">
            <ul> <li> At least one UPPER letter is allowed  </li> </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.hasError('atLeastOneNumeric')">
            <ul> <li> At least one NUMERIC letter is allowed  </li> </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.hasError('atLeastOneSpecialChar')">
            <ul> <li> At least one SPECIAL-CHARACTER is allowed  </li> </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.hasError('atLeastOneEightLength')">
            <ul> <li> At least Eight Letter is allowed  </li> </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
</form>
```